# Sql, one-to-many select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Здравствуйте. Пусть есть две таблицы.

```
create table `houses` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `address` varchar(100) not null,
  primary key(`id`)
);

create table `doors` (
  `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `house_id` int unsigned not null,
  `color` enum('green','red','yellow') not null,
  primary key(`id`)
);
```

Как написать запрос, чтоб выбрать, например, все дома, имеющие красные двери И не имеющие зеленых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов (через вложенный запрос) может выглядеть так

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  houses
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT
           house_id
         FROM
           doors
         WHERE
           color = 'red'
         ) AND
  id NOT IN (SELECT
           house_id
         FROM
           doors
         WHERE
           color = 'green'
         )
```

Comment: @Mike спасибо за уточнение, поправил ответ.

Comment: А возможен другой вариант запроса с тем же результатом?